# How does String.CompareTo work?

Tags: c#, string, compare

When I compare strings containing positive/negative numbers, for example:

```
int res1 = "-1".CompareTo("1");
int res2 = "-1".CompareTo("2");
```

> res1 equals 1.
>   res2 equals -1.

How does String.CompareTo work?? That would mean it is order is "2 -1 1"...

Comment: C# doesn't work like some scripting languages that might compare these values as numbers.  If you really want to compare the numerical values, you need to convert them to a numerical type such as Int32, etc.

Comment: Not an option. I was sorting strings. Those string just happened to have a number at the end (same beginning), and the sort order was strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx):

> Certain nonalphanumeric characters
>   might have special weights assigned to
>   them. For example, the hyphen ("-")
>   might have a very small weight
>   assigned to it so that "coop" and
>   "co-op" appear next to each other in a
>   sorted list.

Edit: Forgot to mention, this is related to the `CompareOptions` enumeration used by `string.Compare`.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, since it addresses the the actual oddity, instead of assuming something and claiming the behaviour makes sense from that assumption.